# how to fix the list-style-type issue in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

```
.footercontainer ul li 
 {
     color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
     font-family: 'opensans-regular';
     font-size: 18px; list-style-type:decimal-leading-zero;
 }

 .footercontainer{  margin:0 auto;  overflow: auto; width:79%;}
 .footleft{ max-width: 49%;/*margin-left:12em; */float:left; margin-left: 2.8em; }
 .footright{max-width: 47%; float:right;/* margin-right: 6%;*/ padding-bottom: 2%;}
 .footercontainer h2{margin-left:0; color:white; font-family:'open_sansbold';}
 .footercontainer ul{max-width:90%; margin:0; padding-bottom:2%;}
 .footleft li{ padding:2px 0 0 0;}

 .footercontainer ul li
  {
    color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
    font-family: 'opensans-regular';
    font-size: 18px;
 list-style-type:decimal-leading-zero;
  }
  .footright li{  font-family:'opensans-regular';color:#E8E8E8; /*margin:3%;*/ }
 .footreadmore{ float:right; width:20%; }
 .footreadmore img {float:right; max-width:100%;} 
 .footreadmore h3{color:#FFFFFF; font-size:90%; text-align="center"}
 .footleft h3{  font-size:100%;}
 .fool{ max-width:97%; margin-left:3%; }

  <div class ="footercontainer">

        <div class="footleft float-left">
            <section>
            <h2>FAQ's in Website Design Services</h2>
            <ul class="clearfix">
            <li>
            <div class="clearfix faq-content">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing           elit. Sed laoreet bibendum auctor.</span>
    <p class="faq float-right">- laoreet biben</p>
            </div>
    </li>
            <li>
    <div class="clearfix faq-content">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet bibendum auctor.</span>
    <p class="faq float-right">- laoreet biben</p>
            </div>
            </li>
    <li>
    <div class="clearfix faq-content">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet bibendum auctor.</span>
    <p class="faq float-right">- laoreet biben</p>
            </div>
            </li>
            </ul>
            <!--<div class="footreadmore"><img src="webdesign/readmore.png" />
            </div>-->
            <span class="more float-right">More..</span>
        </section>
        </div>
        <div class="footright float-right">
          <section>
            <h2>Recent Posts from Web Designing</h2>

             <div class="foo1">
                 <ul class="clearfix">
        <li>
                        <div class="post clearfix">
                        <span class="float-left" id="image1"><img src="webdesign/img1.png"></span>
                     <div class="post-contents float-right ">
            <span id="topics">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
                    <div class="img-description ">
                <p>Jan 25th 2014</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet bibendum auctor.</p>
                <p class="faq float-right">- laoreet biben</p>
                            </div>
            </div>
                        </div>
        </li>   
         <li>
                        <div class="post clearfix">
                        <span class="float-left" id="image1"><img src="webdesign/img2.png"></span>
                         <div class="post-contents float-right">
                    <span id="topics">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
                <div class="img-description ">
                <p>Jan 25th 2014</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet bibendum auctor.</p>
                <p class="faq float-right">- laoreet biben</p>
                            </div>
            </div>
                        </div>
         </li>
                 </ul>

               </div>

  <span class="more float-right">More..</span>
  </section>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I want to display the decimal numbers parallel to the first and second images,The image shown below will explain it well and clear what im coming to say.

[image]

I want a output as below:
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/4Cr8h/
I'm getting this issue in google chrome itself.IE and FF shows perfect result.
Tell some suggestion.

Comment: We need more code to understand why this is happening, could you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: what's mean as jsfiddle?

Comment: seems that the issue comes from another code... sure that's not because of this that we could see.

Comment: @Kiruthiga right here: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Your fiddle works in Chrome for me. Maybe you've left an element open where it shouldn't be, run the code through W3C Validator for help.